# Creating User and Daemon threads simultaneously not working

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I am creating two threads within the main method say t1 and t2.
t1 is user thread and has a loop of 10 print statements
t2 is daemon thread and has a loop of 10 print statements

main starts both threads and has a single print statement.
however even after main exits t2 still continues to run parallel to t1 even after main has ended.
can a daemon thread run even after the thread from which it is created has exited.

kindly update
thanks
tejinder

Answer (score 1):

> can a daemon thread run even after the thread from which it is created has exited.

Yes.  A daemon thread will run until either it exits or *all* non-daemon threads finish and the JVM terminates.  The operation or termination of the parent thread that started the child thread does not affect the child thread at all.

If you want to stop a child thread then the parent thread should `interrupt()` it and then `join()` with it.  Something like:

```
Thread child = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
child.start();
...
child.interrupt();
child.join();
```

Remember that `interrupt()` does *not* cancel the thread.  It just makes methods like `Thread.sleep()`, `Object.wait()`, and others throw `InterruptedException`.  Your child thread should do something like:

```
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      ...
      try {
          Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // catching the exception clears the interrupt bit so we need to set it again
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          // we probably want to quit the thread if we were interrupted
          return;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from where ever you start the threads, threads run independently.